# decrease top height of a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problem with my scrollbar. I want to decrease some height of my scrollbar from the top but when i do it also decreases from the bottom too. what can i do so to decrease the top height of the scrollbar.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
cursor: move;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment
{
height: 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:increment 
{
height: 0px;               // when i change here both top and bottom height decreases.
overflow: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece 
{
background-color: #1D1D1D;
cursor: move;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical,
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal
{
border: 1px solid grey;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to modify a scrollbar before, but what you're describing is a margin issue, not a height issue. Use `margin-top` to "push" the scroll bar away from the top.